# Tkinter: I can't .insert or .get an empty Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

```
entry = tkinter.Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5).grid(row =0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=20)

def Number_click(number):
    Current = str(entry.get())
    entry.insert(0, Current+str(number))
```

Says

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
> number is a lambda var.....

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
entry = tkinter.Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5)
entry.grid(row =0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=20)
```

It must be on 2 lines

Comment: Can you please give an explanation as to why it should be on 2 lines? Something like: `.grid` returns `None` so `None` is stored in `entry` and not the `tkinter.Entry` object

Comment: also no, it is not necessary for it to be on two lines so that _must_ is out of place, it is still possible to add the `Entry` in one line `Entry(master, textvariable=var, **options).grid(**options)` but as You may have noticed there is a  `texvariable`  which meanst that in the line before You sould write `var = StringVar()` for this to work, and then it is possible to use `var.get()` for the same effect. So Entry can be written in one line and still be used, not that You should, but it is not a _must_

Comment: For Python 3.8+, can use `(entry := Entry(...)).grid(...)`.